# Changing content of application in warden container

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, warden

I've cf application which I pushed and working as expected,now I want to change some file content in RT to avoid re-push.the application in deployed to warden container so it "persist" (for this instance ) in the filesystem of the container,How can I access to this file (i've node application so I guess with the FS module) location. i.e. if I've paused app with the following structure

```
myApp
   folder1
      index.html
```

> 1.if I want to change index html content by override how should I do that?I know the path of myApp/folder1/index.html but how I know
>   **where my app is  located in the container  file system**?
>   2. There is a way when I push application to say where to put the application? I mean in the container filesystem in specific path 
>   e.g. when you create application in windows you decide where to put it...

```
C:\\myApp\folder1\index.html
or 
D:\\myApp\folder1\index.html
```

I know that maybe this is advanced question but your help is appreciated! 
p.s. lets say that I've some proxy for the application in the app container which listen to the app port and this can do some changes on the files of the applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing directly to the container file system is not the right approach, because Cloud Foundry containers are intended to be ephemeral and transient.

Let's say that I have one instance of an application running, in Container A, and I change the contents of folder1/index.html. If that instance fails, and is automatically restarted by Cloud Foundry, the new instance won't have the persisted changes. If I need to scale up to 3 instances of my application, then Containers B and C won't have the changed files.

Allowing Cloud Foundry to manage the container file system will assure that you have consistent, repeatable behavior in your application.

If you need to make file changes in your Cloud Foundry application instance, the two recommended approaches are:

- Read and write your file from a file service that is managed by Cloud Foundry. This will ensure that all application instances are accessing the same file system, and that your changes will survive beyond the container lifecycle.
- Make the changes in your application artifact, and re-push the application.

Comment: Thanks cepage,I know that this is advanced topic and not trivial..Correct I know that the container is ephemeral this is how warden is working and I take that in account ...make changes in app and do re-push will take some time which can be a hell during development cycle...lets say I still need to do that,can you provide hint/example.?Thank you sir!!!

Comment: Yes, the easiest way to do this is to use the CLI plugin here: https://github.com/danhigham/cf-console This will create a terminal session you can use to access the file system. The specifics of where in the file system your application is located will depend on the buildpack

Comment: Thanks a lot voted up,can you please provide some hint/example how can I from the build-pack to specify  the application  location ?Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at the bin/compile script of your buildpack to see how paths are set up, but the easier approach may be just to execute a find command to locate the resource you are trying to update.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. lets assume that I use the nodejs buildpackhttps://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack where is the place which provide the location ? can you please provide example for the find you mention this can be very helpful since i didnt found any docs on it.